# How to update a property in an Entity in Cosmos table API using Python

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I have the below table in CosmosDB.

```
PartitionKey  Rowkey  Group  Salary
John          HR      A      100000
Mark          DOC     B      200000
```

I want to update the Salary property in the first entity.
When I tried to update the salary property in the first entity, the complete entity is being replaced instead of updating the salary property.

Could someone let me know how to update an property in a entity in CosmosDB table API.

```
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
from datetime import datetime


my_entity = {
   "PartitionKey" : "John",
    "RowKey" : "HR",
    "Group": "A",
    "Salary": 100000
  
}
table_service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="")
table_client = table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name="my_table")

entity = table_client.create_entity(entity=my_entity)


created = table.get_entity(partition_key=my_entity["PartitionKey"], row_key=my_entity["RowKey"])
created["Salary"] = "200"
table.update_entity(mode=UpdateMode.REPLACE, entity=created)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by changing the following lines of code:

```
created = table.get_entity(partition_key=my_entity["PartitionKey"], row_key=my_entity["RowKey"])
created["Salary"] = "200"
table.update_entity(mode=UpdateMode.REPLACE, entity=created)
```

with

```
created = table_client.get_entity(partition_key=my_entity["PartitionKey"], row_key=my_entity["RowKey"])
created["Salary"] = "200"
table_client.update_entity(mode=UpdateMode.MERGE, entity=created)
```

Comment: I am getting the below error. function' object has no attribute 'get_entity'. Am I missing any cosmos table service import statement?

Comment: Shouldn’t you be using table_client?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.